# Get the index from the comparison of two different length arrays

Tags: perl, comparison, matching

```
#!usr/bin/perl -W

use strict;

my @a = (3,5,8,6,7,9);
my @b = (3,7,8);
my @index;
my $match;

foreach my $i (0 .. $#a) {
    $match = 0;
    foreach my $j (0 .. $#b) {
        if ($a[$i] == $b[$i]) {
            $match = 1;
            push (@index, $j);
            last;
        }            
    }
    if ($match == 1) {
        print "the values which got matched are $a[$i] at a and index is $i\n";
    }
}

print "the index of b matched is @index";
```

Hi I want to get the indices and the values where the array elements got matched.

```
my @a=(3,5,8,6,7,9); 
my @b=(5,9,3);
```

I want to compare @a and @b and get the index of matched value from a. 
(compared values,ia)
output to be something like this ([5,9,3],[1,5,0]). b value 5 is matching at a in index 1.

Can someone help me with this.  I was trying to get first the matched array elements and push the index when match is found. But am not getting the expected result.

Comment: SO is not a free code writing service. Can you please edit the question to show  what you have already attempted.

Comment: IF i add != and extract the elements when match =0 am getting the output of elements which is not present in b. But i wanted the matched elements and their indices .

Comment: your code does not even compile

Comment: I've improved the indentation of your code. You're welcome, but please do it yourself in the future. Properly indented code is far simpler to read and understand.

Comment: `if ($match = 1)` - did you mean that? I suspect you actually wanted `if ($match == 1)` or even just `if ($match)`.

Comment: sorry $match ==1

Comment: Thank you  Dave Cross. From next time i will improve the indentation.

Comment: @Komala: So was `$match = 1` a bug in your program or a mistake you made when re-typing your code on this site? If it's the latter, then you should *always* copy and paste code onto this site. Please don't ever re-type code here as we'll waste time fixing typos instead of the actual problems in your code (as I potentially just did!)

Comment: @Komala: Also, now you know about the problem, why haven't you [edited your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52494508/edit) to fix it?

Comment: re-typing. The code i not giving the result as I wanted, I was checking with different ways, but $match =1 is typo error

Answer (score 1):

### Why your code does not work

You have a fairly simple typo in your code.

```
#                 V
if ($a[$i] == $b[$i]) {
    $match = 1;

    #              V
    push (@index, $j);
    last;
}
```

You are using the `$i` index of the current element in `@a` to access the same value in `@b` every time, and then push `$j` which you never used to compare. You need to compare `$a[$i]` with `$b[$j]`. That one letter change will make the program work.

```
if ($a[$i] == $b[$j]) {
    $match = 1;
    push (@index, $j);
    last;
}
```

### A better way to do it

Your implementation is very inefficient. What you want to do is look up stuff from `@b` for `@a`. An easy way to do that is to build a lookup hash (or an *index*, like the letters on the side of a phone book).

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.012; # for say and each on array

my @a = ( 3, 5, 8, 6, 7, 9 );
my @b = ( 5, 9, 3 );
my @index;
my $match;

my %index_of_a;
while ( my ( $index, $value ) = each @a ) {
  $index_of_a{$value} = $index;    # will overwrite
}

foreach my $value (@b) {
  if ( exists $index_of_a{$value} ) {
    say "The index of '$value' in \@a is '$index_of_a{$value}'";
  }
}
```

The code iterates over the values of `@a`. It uses the [array form of `each`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/each.html)<sup>1</sup>, which was added in Perl 5.12. It then puts them in a hash by value, so you can look up the index when you know a value.

We then iterate the values in `@b` and check if there is an index for `@a` in our hash for the current value.

The output looks like this

```
The index of '5' in @a is '1'
The index of '9' in @a is '5'
The index of '3' in @a is '0'
```

If a value exists in `@a` more than once, the last occurrence will be used. My code does not keep track of which index of `@b` matched when. I will leave that to you.

---

<sup>1) while I generally don't like to use `each`, for arrays where you want both the value and the index I find it a lot more readable than a C-style `for` loop.</sup>

Comment: Hi thank you for the answer. I have one more query @a=(3,5,8,6,7,9,9,8); then can i get the multiple index value when it is matched ? i.e., the index of '9' in @a is  5 ,6 ?

Comment: @Komala you would have to use an array reference as the value of the lookup hash and push the indexes in there. If you don't know what that means, I suggest you take a look at http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html.

Comment: In other words, replace `$index_of_a{$value} = $index;` with `push @{ $indexes_of_a{$value} }, $index;`